# create new df with value from list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df and list of value and I want to create new df with only value from list. What should I do?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4,6], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5,1]}) 
list_of_values = [3,6] 
result= df.query("A in @list_of_values")
print(result)
```

This is what I have:

```
   A  B
1  6  2
2  3  3
4  6  1
```

This is what I want:

```
   A  B
0  6  2
1  3  3
2  6  1
```

Comment: You can `reset_index` but are you sure you want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a `drop=True` under `reset_index()`:

```
result= df.query("A in @list_of_values").reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [5,6,3,4,6], 'B' : [1,2,3, 5,1]}) 
list_of_values = [3,6] 
result= df.query("A in @list_of_values").reset_index(drop=True)
print(result)

   A  B
0  6  2
1  3  3
2  6  1
```